# Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error : Status code '401'

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, jwt, signalr

I'm using SignalR and angular to create a chat between clients, after the client logged in successfully with jwt token. Once I've added -

```
[Authorize]
```

to my hub, I'm getting this error while trying to connect to SignalR -

> Debug: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: : Status code '401''.

Before I added this attribute, my app connected successfully to SignalR so I know the problem is authorization. What am I doing wrong?

UserHub-

```
[Authorize]
public class UserHub : Hub
```

Program.cs-

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<TalkBackDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TalkBackConnectionString")));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IContactRepository, ContactsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IWebAPIService, WebAPIService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISignalrService, SignalrService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSignalR(); 
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/user")))
            {
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Client-

```
public startSignalrConnection(connectionUrl: any) {
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(connectionUrl, { 
      withCredentials: false,
    accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem('jwt')!,
   })
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
    .build();
```

Comment: In the client-side code, you are trying to pass the JWT token to the hub connection via the accessTokenFactory property in the options object when creating the hub connection. But you are not passing the token with the credentials property set to true.

Try
`{
withCredentials: true,
accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem('jwt')!
}`
to the options object when creating the hub connection on the client side. This will send the JWT token in the request headers with the "Authorization: Bearer {token}" format, and the server will be able to read the token and authorize the connection.

Comment: I've changed it to 'true' but I'm still getting the same error: "Error while establishing signalr connection:Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: : Status code '401' " . Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you add any kind of auth information into your http calls? Like an auth interceptor or similar.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, I saw all over the internet that `accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem('jwt')!` should be enough

Comment: Did you save any kind of jwt informations into your localstorage?

Comment: yes I did save the jwt token on local storage. that's why I'm using `localStorage.getItem('jwt')!` but it doesn't seem to fix the problem and I don't know how to locate the error

Comment: You could start to look at the initial http call with your favorite dev tools and check if your jwt was correctly added to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries, I found out what was the problem.
I missed this line on Program.cs -

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I've also edited my token (on another microservice) to be the same like here, and added this line -

```
ValidateIssuerSigningKey=true
```

Now I can access to SignalR.